# How to get many references to one object, using SlotMap?

Tags: rust, ownership

```rs
enum List<'a> {
    Cons(isize, &'a List<'a>),
    Nil,
}

fn main() {
    use List::*;
    use slotmap::SlotMap;
    let mut table = SlotMap::new();
    let nil = table.insert(Nil);
    table.insert(Cons(1, table[nil]));
}
```

[`SlotMap<K: Key, V>`](https://docs.rs/slotmap/latest/slotmap/struct.SlotMap.html)'s [`insert`](https://docs.rs/slotmap/latest/slotmap/struct.SlotMap.html#method.insert) is

```
pub fn insert(&mut self, value: V) -> K
```

and its [`impl<K: Key, V> Index<K>`](https://docs.rs/slotmap/latest/slotmap/struct.SlotMap.html#impl-Index%3CK%3E) is

```
fn index(&self, key: K) -> &V
```

So surely since I insert `List` into `table`, `table[key]` should return `&List` right?

Why am I getting this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:26
   |
11 |     table.insert(Cons(1, table[nil]));
   |                  ----    ^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |       |
   |                  |       expected `&List<'_>`, found enum `List`
   |                  |       help: consider borrowing here: `&table[nil]`
   |                  arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
   |
```

How should I actually be using SlotMap to get many (immutable) references to SlotMap-owned objects?

Comment: The indexing operator `data[index]` automatically dereferences. It's essentially equivalent to `*data.index(index)`.

Comment: Your code still has the same issue as your previous question. You need to change `Cons` to hold the `nil` key directly instead of a reference into the table. You can't hold a reference into the table and modify the table by inserting at the same time.

Comment: @PitaJ do you know if there are any map types that guarantee they won't reallocate memory on insert? can an `insert` method ever feasibly borrow self instead of &mut self?

Comment: Here's one that appears to have such guarantees: https://docs.rs/pinus/latest/pinus/sync/struct.PineMap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `index()` returns a `&V`, but the operator `[]` works such that `a[b]` is equivalent to `*a.index(b)`.

Which is handy, because when you write for example an array:

```
let mut a = [1,2,3];
a[0] = 0;
```

you don't want to write `*a[0] = 0;`! And consider arrays of arrays... `*(*m[0])[1] = 0;`, that wouldn't be pretty.

So if you want the reference to the value just reborrow (that is what the compiler suggests):

```
table.insert(Cons(1, &table[nil]));
```

Or alternatively call `index` manually:

```
table.insert(Cons(1, table.index(nil)));
```

But that begs the question, if you are adding all your lists and partial lists to the slotmap, why not:

```
enum List {
    Cons(isize, Key),
    Nil,
}
```

And get rid of lifetime issues forever?

Comment: In reborrowing `&table[nil]`, does this reference the `List` owned by the SlotMap, or the list moved from the SlotMap to the current scope? (which is what I think `*table.index(nil)` does)

Comment: In my recursive type `Cons(isize, Indirect<List>)`, I want to be able to compare equivalence of `List` as inexpensively as possible. Using `&List` should let me use `std::ptr::eq`, which would be the fastest. I'm not sure if using any wrappers will let me do the same. I also thought trying to use lifetimes would be good practise and/or a good way to ensure memory safety.

Comment: You can't move a value from the SlotMap using the `[]` operator. If you try `let l = table[x];` you will get something like _cannot move out of index of `SlotMap<...>`_.

Comment: Well, if you are willing to use `ptr::eq` for comparison is because you are not comparing the contents of the list but whether they are actually the same object. If all objects are inside a SlotMap, you could as well just compare the keys.

Comment: I think `Key == Key` is not as fast as `ptr::eq`

Comment: `Key`s are just two `u32`s, which is the same size as a pointer on 64-bit systems. So it's likely the comparison will be equally as fast. It's hard to say without actual benchmarks or looking at assembly, but this seems like extremely premature optimization.

Comment: @PitaJ: Indeed, recursive linked lists are probably the slowest container ever devised, so worrying about the speed of comparing keys is quite moot, IMO.

Comment: @PitaJ how do you know that a Key is just a `u32` ?

Comment: I went to the [documentation for `Key`](https://docs.rs/slotmap/latest/slotmap/trait.Key.html) which mentioned it's "intended to be a thin wrapper around `KeyData`", so I went to the [`KeyData` source code](https://docs.rs/slotmap/latest/src/slotmap/lib.rs.html#261-264) which shows it's a `u32` and a `NonZeroU32` (just a special `u32`).

Comment: If later, a `List` is created that is coincidentally equivalent to one that the slot map has already stored, is there any way to get the `Key` for the stored item, instead of having "duplicate" values in the SlotMap?

Comment: I guess you could implement `Hash` and store the lists in a `HashMap` or `BTreeMap`, but then using two containers (slotmap and a hashmap) to handle your home-made `List` somewhat effiently is a bit weird.